# What does the <> operator mean

Tags: haskell, operators, functor

What does the operator **<>** mean/do in the following code?

```
class Functor f => Foldable f where
    fold    :: Monoid m =>             f m -> m
    foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m

instance Foldable [] where
    fold = foldr (<>) mempty
```

Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an operator from [Data.Monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html):

```
(<>) = mappend‌​
```

You can often [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3C%3E) or [Hayoo](http://holumbus.org/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=%3C%3E) for such operators.